# What is the alternative function in HarmonyOS for onMeasure in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK.
In order to negotiate the width and height of the custom view in Android, we override [`onMeasure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onMeasure(int,%20int)).

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {}
```

What is the alternative for the above in HarmonyOS?

Comment: Welcome to the community Yogesh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android - [onMeasure()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onMeasure(int,%20int)) is a protected method available in [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) class so one can directly override it in custom component by extending the View class.

For alternative in HarmonyOS - you will have to implement [Component.EstimateSizeListener](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/component_estimatesizelistener-0000001078480100) in your custom component and then write down the implementation in overriden function [onEstimateSize](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/component_estimatesizelistener-0000001078480100#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001078480100__onEstimateSize-int-int-).

**So in Android, when you have some code like this -**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

   public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   }
}
```

**Harmony Code changes will be -**

```
public class CustomComponent implements ComponentContainer.EstimateSizeListener

public CustomComponent(Context context, AttrSet attrSet, String styleName) {
       super(context, attrSet, styleName);
       setEstimateSizeListener(this); //set the listener here
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onEstimateSize(int widthEstimatedConfig, int heightEstimatedConfig) {
   }
}
```